# Difference between fsarchiver and dump

Tags: filesystems, backup, ext4, utilities

What is the difference between [dump](http://dump.sourceforge.net/) and [fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/)?

Are there features in `dump` which are not covered by `fsarchiver`?
Can both backup to tape storage for example?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to pursue?

Comment: @Braiam to me it looks like dump and fsarchiver do the same job, but fsarchiver is newer and seems to have more features.